# Scala date format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a data_date that gives a format of yyyymmdd:

```
beginDate = Some(LocalDate.of(startYearMonthDay(0), startYearMonthDay(1), 
startYearMonthDay(2)))
var Date = beginDate.get
.......

val data_date = Date.toString().replace("-", "")
```

This will give me a result of '20180202'
however, I need the result to be 201802 (yyyymm) for my usecase. I don't want to change the value of beginDate, I just want to change the data_date value to fit my usecase, how do I do that? is there a split function I can use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to to it with DateTimeFormatter.

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YMM")
val data_date = Date.format(foramatter)
```

*I recommend you to read through `DateTimeFormatter` docs, so you can format date the way you want.*

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the code snippet that you're using Spark, but the tags imply that, so I'll give an answer using Spark built-in functions.  Suppose your `DataFrame` is called `df` with date column `my_date_column`.  Then, you can simply use [`date_format`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@date_format(dateExpr:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,format:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.date_format
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.date_format

scala> df.withColumn("my_new_date_column", date_format($"my_date_column", "YYYYMM")).
     | select($"my_new_date_column").limit(1).show

// for example:
+------------------+
|my_new_date_column|
+------------------+
|            201808|
+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by only taking the first 6 characters of the resulting string.
i.e.

```
val s = "20180202"
s.substring(0, 6) // returns "201802"
```